# How to redirect to next page after clicking sign in and check user credentials are correct or not

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

In this I'm trying to define a login form and authenticate user from the database to match the login and password fields.But not able to redirect to next page when I click on Sign in button.
/* This is my LoginAuthenticator for loginPage */

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Container7sZvbGR\getDashboardControllerService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\PassportInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface
    {
        $userEmail = $request->request->get('user_email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $userEmail);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($userEmail),
            new PasswordCredentials($request->request->get('password', 'Pomelo')),

            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $request->get('_csrf_token')),

            ]

        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {

        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_dashboard'));
        //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $request->attributes->get('_route') === 'app_dashboard'
            && $request->isMethod('POST');;
    }

}
```

/*This is my security.yaml file*/

```
security:

    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: app_logout
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

/*This is my login.html.twig to display the page content */

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Log in!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<form>
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if app.user %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            You are logged in as {{ app.user.username }}, <a href="{{ path('app_logout') }}">Logout</a>
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <label for="inputUser_email">User_email</label>
    <input type="email" value="{{ last_username }}" name="user_email" id="inputUser_email" class="form-control" autocomplete="email" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" required>

    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
    >

    {#
        Uncomment this section and add a remember_me option below your firewall to activate remember me functionality.
        See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

        <div class="checkbox mb-3">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="_remember_me"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>
    #}

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
        Sign in
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

/*
This is my login controller for login page
*/

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // if ($this->getUser()) {
        //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
        // }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

Comment: "not able to" doesn't really explain the problem...what exactly is happening when you run the code?

Comment: When I enter username and password and click sign it is not routing to next page. I was not able to check weather the user credentials are correct or not.

Comment: Ok and what debugging have you done?

Answer (score 1):

The login authenticator checks the credentials for you automatically.

This method is what handles where to go after a successful login.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
{

    // For example:
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_dashboard'));
    //throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
}
```

If you are not being sent to the app_dashboard route then your login is not successfully authenticating.

Make sure to check the database for the user you are trying to log in as and ensure the details for that user are what you expect.

I also recommend uncommenting this in your login controller so that logged-in users are redirected from the login page to the "target_path"

```
    // if ($this->getUser()) {
    //     return $this->redirectToRoute('target_path');
    // }
```

Comment: No I tried to add dashboard controller in the form action in login controller so it is redirecting to next page if i click sign in. <form action="dashboard" method="post">

Comment: @ManojReddy Add just the method="post" to your form and not the action.